# ¿Cómo cambio <title> al nombre de una tabla en mi BD?

Tags: php, javascript, html

tengo una web que imprime imágenes de una bd, en si es solo el nombre de la imagen, pero quiero que cada vez que le de click a la imagen me cambie el titulo al de la imagen, intente con JS con pero no me salio, seguramente mi código esta mal.

```
function TitleChange() {
    document.title = "<?php $query = "SELECT Name FROM Titles"; ?>";
}
```

Este me daba error: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**

Y si cambio las comillas a comillas simples el titulo me cambia a todo el testo, porque lo toma como un string, especificamente esta sección es la que muestra en el titulo:

```
<?php $query = 'SELECT Name FROM Titles'; ?>
```

Intente con un WHERE pero después de eso me bloque, hice algo así:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function TitleChange() {
    document.title = "<?php  $query = "SELECT Name FROM champions WHERE ID Like 3"; ?>";
    }
</script>
```

Y el resultado fue **localhost/BOL/** (Que es la dirección de la página).

Me podrían ayudar, solamente quiero tomar el dato Name de la bd, porfavor, no hablo bien ingles por eso pregunto en español.

Comment: Necesitas primero conseguir el resultado de la consulta `$resultado = mysql_query($query)` y después `document.title = "<?php echo $resultado; ?>`

Comment: La pregunta no es clara. Si tienes ya todas las imágenes cargadas y lo que quieres es cambiar el `title` de la página u otro elemento cuando se haga click en las imágenes no necesitas volver a consultar en el servidor, puedes guardar el dato en cada imagen y usarlo cuando se haga click en ella, eso te evitará constantes idas y vueltas al servidor sin necesidad.

Comment: Ok, perdón por la tardanza, bueno si yo he pedido las imágenes, pero no se como hacer para que el texto al que cambie sea al de la imagen, estoy nublado y no se me ocurre una linea de código buena

Comment: Esto es lo "mejor" que tengo:
`<?php  
 include('conex.php');

 $query = "SELECT * FROM champions WHERE Name = '$resultado'";
 $resultado = $conex->query($query);
 $fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function OpenChamp() {
  document.title = "<?php  echo $fila['Name']; ?>";
 }
</script>`

Claramente esta mal porque en el query busco los resultados que sean igual a $resultado, pero aún no inicializo la variable, que cambio o borro todo?

Comment: De esa manera el titulo cambia a algo como esto:
**localhost/BOL/#?id=Name1**.
Almenos ahora cambia el titulo, para mi es un avance.